# This script tag working fine in firefox but not in chrome (because getting some security issue)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, proxy, cross-domain

I have a script tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://hostname.com/rootname/dynamicScript?basedOnTheParameter=true"></script>` inside a page.

It's works fine in firefox but chrome saying

[blocked] The page at `https://hostname.com/index.jsp` ran insecure content from `http://hostname.com/rootname/dynamicScript?basedOnTheParameter=true`.

And in IE a security message comes up with two 2 button `yes` or `no`, if i choose yes then script is not accessible but script works in-case `no` button.

Can someone please explain why this happening and what is solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing non-secure information on a secure site (this happens if you reference images, scripts, styles, etc on a HTTP site, from an HTTPS site).  Can you put the files on your HTTPS site?

IE warns the user to let them know that not ALL information will be secure.  If someone is running a packet sniffer, for example, all content from HTTPS will be encrypted, but the scripts coming from your HTTP site won't be.  So the warning lets the user know that they shouldn't have a false sense of security because there's a HTTPS url in their address bar.  It looks like Chrome prevents it altogether, though.

Answer (score 3):

If your page is on HTTPS, you should not load any HTTP URLs, because attackers would be able to modify them and bypass your security.

Depending on browsers and security settings, the user will get different kinds of errors or warnings if you try.